# Описание удалено и ничего не понятно

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, временная-шкала

Во [временной шкале](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/762076/timeline) превращение сообщения из общего в авторское выглядит как

> описание удалено

По-моему, надо эту фразу изменить, либо, в случае, если вариантов описаний для удаления много, добавить комментарий, который сейчас пустует:

> [image: скриншот]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправил на:

> статус общего убран

Ждите на сайте к понедельнику.